# When to use backtracking template and when to not?

Tags: algorithm

I saw a lot of posts about backtracking explanations on SO, but the part which still confuses me is when do I actually use the backtracking template(choose-explore-unchoose) as opposed to a normal DFS mindset while solving problems? I understand that both of them are essentially backtracking, but from the problem solving perspective, a traditional DFS approach feels a lot more intuitive when you see a problem of that sort. But, I wanted to know when your mind should go "choose-explore-unchoose".

For example: if you want to print all root-to-leaf paths,  a simple DFS problem solving approach makes a lot of sense, whereas while printing permutations of a string, we take take the "choose-explore-unchoose" strategy. I am having a difficult time to categorize problems into these 2 buckets. (Categorization is the current strategy im using to make my mind think in a certain direction. If there is any other strategy to solve, anyone is welcome to share.)

Here is the template I am referring to:

```
function dfs(node, state):
    if state is a solution:
        report(state) # e.g. add state to final result list
        return

    for child in children:
        if child is a part of a potential solution:
            state.add(child) # make move
            dfs(child, state)
            state.remove(child) # backtrack
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, DFS is essentially backtracking: choose (child), explore (all his children) and unchoose (move to next child).

There might be some other different approaches for backtracking, but that it depends more on heuristics. If you look for graph algorithms (like "A-star" family algorithms) you will see a lot of backtracking algorithm-styles that differs from DFS. The difference is what heuristics they rely on, and order of search: just like with small change you can get BFS instead of DFS.

There is no "one rule" to know when to use when. Whatever is more intuitive to you is fine, as long as you know how to use all of your toolbox/